# Netsh and httpcfg

Tags: windows, wcf

I have used following command in Win7:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=[http://+:1234/] user=\Everyone
```

But it does not work in WinXP. So I downloaded httpcfg.exe,but cannot find appropriate syntax to convert my original command to httpcfg format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN seems to have an [example for this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786389%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_2). It doesn't seem like you can just specify the user as with `netsh`. `httpcfg` takes a Security Descriptor Definition Language (SDDL) string.

Generating SDDL strings is described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907510/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-sddl-security-descriptor-definition-language-strin). Basically, you can read the [specification](http://www.netid.washington.edu/documentation/domains/sddl.aspx), or you can set the desired permissions on a random file on your system and then use `cacls FILE_PATH /S` to get the SDDL.

So after generating the SDDL, you'd probably want something like:

```
httpcfg set urlacl /u http://+:1234/ /a "<SDDL>"
```